# Referencing object elements

Tags: r, tukey

I'm trying to access individual elements of an object returned from TukeyHSD function. I can see how to access the individual elements, but how do I access the labels?

```
$`Auto$CargoSpace`
                  diff       lwr        upr        p adj
wagon-SUV -3747.333 -7664.507  -980.0801 6.855348e-03
trunk-SUV  -4792.333 -5621.311 -2371.3357 2.065806e-05
trunk-wagon  -968.000 -3823.523  2125.54328 7.410039e-01
```

I'd like to be able to access each row/column combination the way I can with a tibble or dataframe. That way I can add an interpretation later in the code. Let's say I wanted to end up with this result:

CargoSpace  p adj   Analysis

wagon-SUV    6.85   Unlikely to produce a benefit

trunk-SUV    2.06   Worth investigating

Comment: Can you show the expected outupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We extract the output with `$`, then use either `grep` (if partial matches) or `%in%` (for fixed matching) to subset the rows, create a `data.frame` with the row names of the subset of the dataset along with "p adj" column.  Then, we can create 'Analysis' column based on the value of 'p.adj'

```
out1 <- out$`Auto$CargoSpace`
out2 <- out1[grep("SUV$", row.names(out1),]
out3 <- data.frame(CargoSpace = row.names(out2), p.adj = out2[, "p adj"])
out3$Analysis <- ifelse(out2$p.adj < 0.0001, "Worth investigating", "Unlikely to produce a benefit")
```

---

Reproducible example

```
fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
out <- TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", ordered = TRUE)



out$tension
#         diff        lwr      upr       p adj
#M-H  4.722222 -4.6311985 14.07564 0.447421021
#L-H 14.722222  5.3688015 24.07564 0.001121788
#L-M 10.000000  0.6465793 19.35342 0.033626219
```

Comment: I think they want some column from "tension": `out$tension[, "diff" ]`

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to be able to put the column names like "trunk-SUV" and the "p adj" values.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to put them all in a tibble and add a column for an intrepretation that I'll add later.

Comment: @JD08 the `trunk_SUV` is rowname.  Can you update your post with the expected output